# image animated resize and blur with jquery

Tags: jquery, resize, scale, blur, animated

I have an image that I want to resize after page load to fit its parent (maybe using little animation) and then blur. Any tips?

Thanks!

L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var img = $('.anImage'),
    offset = img.offset();

// position image absolutely in the same position to allow it to expand
img.css({
       position: "absolute",
       top: offset.top,
       left: offset.left,
       zIndex: 100
   })
   // animate expansion
   .animate({
       top: 0,
       left: 0,
       width: img.parent().width(),
       height: img.parent().height()
   }, "fast")
   // fadeout
   .fadeOut("fast");
```

The only requirement is that you leave the parent element with `position: relative`.

Comment: this works great, I only had to change the fadeout to .fadeTo('slow', 0.3)! Thank you very much!!!